# Laravel API too slow when the Node server is running and consuming it

Tags: node.js, laravel

I have a Vue front end and a Node app, these two applications consume the same API made in Laravel, the differential of the app in Node is that it is more "worker", every 10 seconds it makes requests for that same API. When I call the Node application the Vue front end requests to the API are very slow, a simple get arrives take minutes, when I disconnect the server node the front end is able to communicate quickly with the API, someone has already passed this problem?

Comment: `someone has already passed this problem` - What problem? This is super specific to your case. Sounds like more a bottle neck at MySQL than it does at Laravel as your `Vue` frontend will be using the workers forked by `ngnix/apache` whereas your node worker does not, so the bottleneck likely isn't the Laravel application but rather a leak in your `node` code or a problem with resource limitations on your machine. But we have no way of knowing and without you showing detailed profiling information and code we cannot help you. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I've never been through this sort of problem. I have a function setInterval in the Node that gets consuming the Laravel API, if I take this function, it works very well, but then my application will not run more every X seconds.

Comment: Make sure you're only executing that code in `setInterval` if the previous job loop has finished. If not you will hammer your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" is that I was running setInterval on the Node to consume the API, now I changed through cron.schedule (a library from cron to node) and got real fast!

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   consumeLaravelApi(); 
}, 10000);
```

To

```
cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
  consumeLaravelApi();
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron